# How to speed up loading / playing video in a Next.js / React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, html5-video, h.264

I have this page in a Next.js site:

https://sendmade-portal-vercel.vercel.app/hu/product/repityke-origami-penztarca

You can feel video loads slowly.

This is how `video` element is used:

```
<video
  width="100%"
  autoPlay
  muted
  loop
  playsInline
  style={{
    position: "absolute",
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    zIndex: -1,
  }}
>
  <source
    src={`http://ticket-t01.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/${props.urlPrefix}-intro.mp4`}
    type="video/mp4"
  />
</video>
```

Video is H.264 encoded, and has a 3840 × 2160 resolution. Shall I reduce the resolutiion? Would it help? Do you have any other idea? Said that Next.js does not have video optimization as there is image optimization.

Comment: For the starters, I would suggest removing the audio from your video as you are using it just for background. Secondly, a 4K video is surely not required. Even a 720p video will look smooth on most of the screens. Third, your video is of around 1.5min. This is more than required. Try limiting your video to less than 30s. Fourth, provide a `poster` attribute to your video element. Fifth, provide multiple video sources (first in some next gen formats like webm, then in more compatible ones like mp4). Sixth, no Next.js does not provide you with video optimization components.

Comment: You can also use some next-gen image formats like animated webp, and add your video as a fallback. You can also play around better codecs like VVC or AV1. But their support is limited, so you will have to add multiple fallback sources to deliver the shortest one first.

Comment: If you want to do video backgrounds, you need to be aware of how limited bandwidth is and load a smaller video. @brc-dd is correct

Comment: What if I postpone video to start, or even not autoplay the video? Does it improve user experience, load faster the page?

Answer (score 0):

The video is a static asset so you can just convert the `mp4` video to `webm` before serving it. You can also use something like WebRTC if you want to implement streaming, though if the webm size is small enough that won't be necessary.

There is an [RFC](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/56118) for `next/video` for auto webm conversion + streaming but so far doesn't seem like it has been implemented.